# How to change iconfont's default font size and repackage?

Tags: javascript, icons

For example, the google icon, the default is 24px, and the text content of my webpage uses 14px, so when I use the google icon, there will be some problems, mainly the line height, for example, when the text of the icon is placed on the button, the height of my button Destroyed, but when I use css to change the google icon to 14px, it is too small, which is not what I want.

I have an idea now, to preset the google font to 14px, but the actual size is the same as 24px, and finally repackage for my webpage, then I can keep the text content and icon at 14px and keep the appearance perfect, Is this possible?

Will there be some automatic generation tools? For example javascript libs or gulp plugin?